# Need two regular expressions

Tags: regex

I am a real newbie regarding Regular Expressions (RegEx)

I am looking for a RegEx1 to only match strings containing no spaces.
RegEx2 to only match strings containing spaces.

Example:

RegEx1 must match `"abcxyz"` but NOT `"abc xyz"`.
RegEx2 must match `"abc xyz"` but NOT `"abcxyz"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to learn about [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

`[abc]` matches a character that is either an `a`, a `b` or a `c`.

`[^abc]` matches any character that is neither an `a`, a `b` nor a `c`.

Together with [quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) and start- and end-of-string [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), you're all set.

`^[^X]*$` matches a string of any length that doesn't contain `X`.

`^.*X.*$` matches any string that contains at least one `X`.

`^[^X]*X[^X]*$` matches a string of any length that contains exactly one `X`.

Comment: Thank you @Pietzcker.  In thinking about my question, I realized that I did not need two regex expressions, just one that matches a space.  So my regex is simply [ ]. If there are no spaces, the regex will return FALSE. if there are, it will return TRUE.  Thanks again for your help.